# Javascript ES6 Get an anchor tag inside of the last li item

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, css-selectors

I have a situation where I am trying to get the last li item in my list and then get the anchor tag inside of that last li item so I can change the href value and the text value of the a tags with classname 'buyButton'.

My list looks like the below:

```
<li class="item">
<a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
<a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
</li>
<li class="item">
<a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
<a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
</li>
<li class="item">
<a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
<a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
</li>
<li class="item">
<a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
<a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
</li>
```

My javascript that I am using to select the last list is working. The code is below:

```
var numProducts = document.querySelectorAll('.item').length;
var lastProduct = document.querySelectorAll('.item')[numProducts -1];
```

I am trying the below code to get the anchor tag inside of the last li item but it is not working:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item a.buttonBuy')[numProducts -1]
//not working

document.querySelectorAll('.buttonBuy')[numProducts -1]
//also not working
```

I cannot figure it out at all. Any help on this would greatly appreciated

Comment: `theul.lastChild` would get you the last li, at which point getting either child of the li would be simple, again, using lastChild or firstChild, depending on what you want.

Comment: Also... you've got a typo. `buyButton` vs `buttonBuy`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your last examples aren't working is because you are using the class `buttonBuy` instead of `buyButton` as in your HTML.

The easiest way to perform your request is to use the container to select the last item, then you can select the anchor and modify it as desired:

```js
let link = document.querySelector('ul > .item:last-child > .buyButton');

link.textContent = '*Updated*'
link.href        = 'javascript:alert("foo")'
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
    <a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
    <a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
    <a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="test.html" class="buyButton">Buy</a>
    <a href="compare.html" class="compare">Compare</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Once we have the reference to the last LI, we can querySelectorAll within the LI itself:

```
var aWithinLastProduct = lastProduct.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
```

Comment: you didn't explain why your answer should work and you posted it as plain text, not even edited as code.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer